# VSIntr no data is collected

Tags: c#, dll, profiling, instrumentation, vsperfmon

I am trying to instrument our application looking for performance optimizations, but I cannot manage to get any data out of it. I am mainly interested in function running times and how many times where they were called.

Can you point to the flaw in my process please?

Here is what I do:

**1. VSInstr MyAssembly.dll**

This creates the instumented dll (like twice the size) and backs up the original.
I get a warning about strong-named things so step 2

**2. sn -Ra MyAssembly.dll TheKeyFile.snk**

Says resigning is successfull

**3. VsPerfCLREnv /traceon**

Setting up environment variables

**4. Running the program. I go right before the step I want to investigate.**

**5. VsPerfCmd /start:trace /output:../Reports/Report.vsp**

Starting the trace

**6. Clicking the button to do the process (app creation) and waiting to finish**

**7. VSPerfCmd /shutdown**

Stop tracing.

**8. VSPerfCLREnv /off**

Reset environment to normal

At the end of all this I check the Report.vsp file. It is a 148KB file which when opened in VS2017 throws these two error popups and fails to open anything:

- File contains no data buffers
- Failed to analyse report

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to

- Use /globaltraceon instead of /traceon
- First run VsPerfCmd /start:trace and only start the service afterwards
- Call VSPerfCmd /processon:[PID] to attach to process
- Stop the service when finished ( /shutdown won't complete otherwise)

So the steps looked like this:

1. VSInstr MyAssembly.dll
2. sn -Ra MyAssembly.dll TheKeyFile.snk
3. VsPerfCLREnv /globaltraceon
4. Set service on Manual startup
5. Restart computer
6. VsPerfCmd /start:trace /output:Reports/Report.vsp
7. Start service manually
8. VsPerfCmd /processon: (look  up in Task Manager)
9. Do whatever you want to measure
10. Stop service
11. VsPerfCmd /shutdown